# Is There a Practical Encryption Algorithm Which Maintains Comparability

Tags: encryption, compare, comparator

Is there a secure encryption algorithm, which is practical and maintains `comparability`?

For example, if you have strings `A`, `B`, and `C` and `A` < `B` < `C` then if ran through the encryption algorithm it and the resulting values are compared then `enc(A)` < `enc(B)` < `enc(C)`.

I specifically mention practical too, as I don't want `enc(input)` to be too much bigger than `input`.

Comment: That would not be very good encryption. You could "decrypt" by a simple binary-search. In fact, I'd consider it rather bad if `enc(A)` equals `enc(A)` for two separate encryption runs. Even same plaintext should produce different output every time. (And I believe that precludes your requirement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The theoretical ability to do computation has been established, and the field is known as [Homomorphic encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption). It's just not practical.

But just consider what your trivial scheme implies. I can brute force B from enc(B) by doing a binary search. Just start with enc(MIN), enc(MAX) and enc(MIN+MAX/2). enc(B) is bigger or smaller than enc(MIN+MAX/2) which halves the possible range of B. An "encryption" scheme which can be brute forced in O(log N) is **incredibly** poor.

This is effectively solved by "encrypting" > as well.

Comment: I think that's actually O(n^2) in the size of the message, as you'd need one O(n) encryption operation (and one constant-time comparison) for every bit in the message. Even so, that's incredibly bad.

Comment: I had considered N as the size of the search space and enc() as O(1). In hindsight, encryption does tend to use N for the message or key size in bits..